# Is it necessary to add semicolcon for the constructor in the javascript class?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know if I need to add semicolon after the constructor. Looks like adding semicolon or not adding, both are working.

```
function test() {
};

function test2() {}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Show an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you don't *need* to add a semi-colon.

According to an article that covers the topic of [semi-colon necessity in JavaScript](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/) quite thoroughly, these are all valid examples of lines without semi-colons:

```
var a=1
var b=2
var c=3

// before
if(condition) stuff()

// after
if(condition){
  stuff()
}

// after minification
if(condition){stuff()}
```

This, on the other hand, will **not** work:

```
a = b + c
(d + e).print()
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript if two JS statements are seperated by a line then semicolon is present or no it doesn't matter. If the JS statements are combined like in a minified file then semicolon is a must otherwise you will get an error.

Answer (score 0):

[JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html) suggestion
 - JSLint expects that every statement be followed by ; except for for, function, if, switch, try, and while. JSLint does not expect to see unnecessary semicolons or the empty statement.

In your case. I think there's no need to add semicolon

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the semicolon is *not* needed. Or, indeed, expected; the interpreter will ignore it.

But if you were to do this:

```
var test = function() {
    return;
};
```

... the semicolon **is** expected. Because of semicolon insertion, it's not *needed* (your interpreter will "fix" it if you leave it out), but it's generally advised to use it anyway.

The difference is that `function name() {}` is a compound statement, whereas `var name = function() {};` is a simple declaration statement.

*Reference: http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html*